# Where to place nested routes in react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

so basically I am new to `React` and `react-router`. Still learning.

Can someone explain me why this is working:

```
const App = () => (
  <Fragment>

    <Route 
      exact
      path="/"
      render={(props) => <Calendar {...props} />}
    />
    <Route
      path="/:topics"
      render={(props) => <Topics {...props} />}
    />
    <Route
      path="/:topics/:id"
      render={(props) => <Topic {...props} />}
    />
  </Fragment>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>, ROOT);
```

but if I remove nested routes from `App` component and place them in `Topics` and `Topic` components then routing doesn't work.

```
class Topics extends Component {
  render() {
    const {match} = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="topics">

          <Route
            path={`${match.path}/:topics`}
            render={(props) => <Topics {...props} />}
          />
      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

Also which approach is better ? Having all `Route`'s in `App` component or maybe put nested `Route`'s in nested components ?

Comment: Personally I'd define a route for `/:topics/:id?` (mind the question mark) and let the corresponding container for `Topics` decide which presentational component to render, depending on the availability of id. This would clean up your code and remove the necessity to define further routes outside of `App`.

Comment: what stays in your `<App />` when you move routes out of it?

Comment: @skyboyer only this `<Route 
      exact
      path="/"
      render={(props) => <Calendar {...props} />}
    />`

Comment: how `<Topics />` should be rendered then once it is not inject anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to write a routes component

```
export default class Routes extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <Switch>
    <Route path='your path' component={yourcomponent} />
  </Switch>
);
}
}
```

and then in the app component I call it as a child

```
  <Router history={history}>
    <Routes />
  </Router>
```

so I can control routes in isolated way from the app

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using [react-router-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom). Especially if you are developing for browser purpose.

I Usually declare my BrowserRouter (as Router) in my index.js and wrap it around my App component like this:

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <App />
    </Router>
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Then I call the Route component from react-router-dom in my App.js component and declare it at the beginning of my file, like this:

**App.js**

```
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'
// IMPORT COMPONENTS

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Route exact path='/'           component={ HomePage }/>
                <Route exact path='/home'       component={ HomePage }/>
                <Route exact path='/discover'   component={ Discover }/>
                <Route exact path='/purchase'   component={ Purchase }/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

After you've done this you can route from every component by using the Link component. Also provided by react-router-dom.

**Example component** (HomePage.js)

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

class HomePage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='HomePage'>
                <p>Press the button below to route to our Discovery page!</p>

                <Link to='/discover'>
                    <button>Press me</button>
                </Link>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

---

This is just a basic example. You can find more info and options right [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) or on there [Github page](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides).

Comment: then if i have nested links/components, like planets .. would I also write it this way?

            <div className="App">
                <Route exact path='/'           component={ HomePage }/>
                <Route exact path='/home'       component={ HomePage }/>
                <Route exact path='/discover'   component={ Discover }/>
                <Route exact path='/discover/planet'   component={ Planets }/>
                 <Route exact path='/discover/planet/earth'   component={ Earth }/>
            </div>